# multiple id row to single row sql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have these two tables. The first one is **product_to_category**

```
product_id       category_id
   7538               5
   7538             128
   7538             139
```

The second one is **category_description**

```
category_id       name
     5            toys
   128        toys for kids
   139        teddy bears
```

I was breaking my head and couldn't get what i want. The name of the categories can change at any time, so it is not an option to use the name of the categories in pivot. **My desired output should be**

```
product_id      category_main     category_sub1     category_sub2
   7538             toys          toys for kids      teddy bears
```

How can this be done? I am not good at sql

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: just in phpmyadmin i have these tables, they are all from opencart.

Comment: phpmyadmin is not a DBMS. It's a frontend to a DBMS named MySQL

Comment: Are there always 3 categories? what are the rules for which is main, which is sub1, which is sub2?

Comment: oh ok. sorry. no, there can be two or one row sometimes. depends on the type of the product it self.

Comment: the main, sub1, and sub2 should be just created upon the query Select statement. I want to break the rows into those columns

Comment: Is the parent category's ID always lower than its sub categories?

Comment: yes, the parent category ID is always lower than the sub

Comment: How do you link teddy bears with toys?

Comment: as you can see in the first table, the product_id repeats its self three times, that is, it takes toys by id, then id toys for kids and then teddy bears. These tables are opencart stuff. The product_id links to category_id and that is all i guess

Answer (score 1):

> How can this be done? I am not good at sql

It cannot be done with the current schema of your DB, since **a link** from the sub categories to the category 'toys' **is missing**!

You will have to include a column **parentId** as already pointed out by others and then manually decide which categories belong to each other.

However, you may find a pattern to update all categories at once.
For example, is the parent category's ID **always** lower than its sub categories?

Comment: yes, the parent category ID is always lower than the sub

Comment: OK, then it's possible to achieve this (!)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
select P.product_id, 
  max(case when rownum = 1 then N.name end) category_main,
  max(case when rownum = 2 then N.name end) category_sub1,
  max(case when rownum = 3 then N.name end) category_sub2
from 
(
  select product_id,
    category_id,
    @row:=if(@prev=product_id,@row,0) + 1 as rownum,
    @prev:=product_id
  from product_to_category
  order by product_id
) P JOIN category_description N on N.category_id = P.category_id
group by P.product_id;
```

Comment: it throws me an error syntax to use near 'P JOIN category_description N on N.category_id = P.category_id group by P.produc' at line 13   (((

Comment: Can you check my query now @user3465207

Comment: now it works, but category_sub1 and category_sub2 shows null. Category _main shows the right thing

Answer (score 0):

add parent column to category_description table like this

```
  category_id       name            parent_id
          5            toys            0
        128            toys for kids   5
        139            teddy bears     5
```

and use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808784/mysql-parent-children-one-query-selection) query's answer.

Comment: there are more than 14000 products. how should i do that?

Comment: I think no way else. You must edit all categories manual or write "util" for replacing parents and childs.

Comment: I see. Oh gosh too bad

Comment: Sorry for bad news :)

Answer (score 0):

Pivoting a table into multiple columns is a bit of a pain.  However, you can easily combine the categories into a single column using `group_concat()`:

```
select product_id, group_concat(name) as names
from product_to_category p2c join
     category_description cd
     on p2c.category_id = cd.category_id
group by product_id;
```

This has the additional advantage that any number of categories can be represented for a given product (up to certain limits for `group_concat()`).