# Doctrine2 w/ child entities in the same table

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a database table that generally (because of a NDA) has the structure of:

```
Category:
id(int)    parent_id(int)    title(string)    description(text)
```

Note that I cannot change the table's schema, so that's not a possible solution to my problem.

I need to be able to get all of these categories' info, including a list of all their children, but I'm not quite sure how to do it.  I'm fairly certain that I'll need to use recursion, but I'm not sure if there's anything built into Doctrine that can aid in it, or if I need to write raw DQL or even SQL.  I currently have the following in my Symfony controller:

```
$em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();

$categoryQuery = $em->getRepository('Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Category')->findBy(array(), array('sortPosition' => 'asc'));
$categories = array();

foreach ($categoryQuery as $category) {
        $categories[] = array(
            'id' => $category->getId(),
            'parent' => $category->getParent(),
            'title' => $category->getTitle(),
            'description' => $category->getDescription(),
        );
}
```

There's another wrinkle: I need to output this info in JSON.

Ultimately, I'm not sure

A. How to create a query that will get me both a category *and* all of its child info (which can have more children)

B. How to then output that info as JSON

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you have the category <> category relation defined in doctrine:**

```
$categoryQuery = $em->getRepository('Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Category')
  ->createQueryBuilder('c')
  ->leftJoin('c.subCategories sc') // assuming your category <> category relation is called "subCategories
  ->getQuery()
  ->getResult()
  ;
```

Then in each record of $categoryQuery you will have a Category and its children in ->subCategories (you dont really need the join there)

**If you dont have a relation defined in doctrine, then:**

```
$query = $em->createQuery(
    'SELECT c
    FROM AcmeMyBundle:Category c
    LEFT JOIN AcmeMyBundle:Category sc on sc.parent_id = c.id
    ORDER BY sortPosition ASC'
);

$categories = $query->getResult();
```

And return them as JSON

```
return new JSONResponse($categories);
```

Answer (score 1):

A. Recursive selection is ... hard/impossible without a path.

See : [MySQL parent children one query selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808784/mysql-parent-children-one-query-selection)

B. You can use this in Symfony2 :

`Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse`