# how to make a tree in sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

how to make a tree in sql , when can the data in this way?

```html
category_id |category_parent |category_code      |category_name        
------------|----------------|-------------------|---------------------
70          |0               |Vege               |Vegetable            
71          |0               |Frui               |Fruit                
72          |0               |Fish               |Fishery              
73          |71              |Butc               |Butchery             
74          |72              |Poul               |Poultry              
75          |73              |Dair               |Dairy                
76          |75              |Deli               |Delicatessen         
77          |75              |Frofod             |Frozen Food          
78          |76              |Foserv             |Food Service         
79          |77              |Pla Flo            |Plant & Flower       
80          |79              |ConFresh           |Consightment Fresh   
81          |79              |Café               |Café
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Oveflow. Please visit the help center and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what to ask and how.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Mysql does not have any recursive function. Use the application level to write a recursive function and then generate the tree.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16808998/1531192 might be useful for you.

Comment: Assuming that `category_parent` is a self-referencing foreign key to `category_id`, what you have described already is a tree.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to look up is Common Table Expression (CTE).
[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/818694/SQL-queries-to-manage-hierarchical-or-parent-child) is a good example for CTE.

So what you want to do looks something like that:

```
WITH Tree(child_category_id, child_name, child_category, parent_id, Parents)
AS
(
--1st level rows (parent)
    SELECT category_id, category_name, category_code, category_parent, CAST('' AS VARCHAR(MAX))
        FROM YourTable AS FirtGeneration
        WHERE category_parent = 0
    UNION ALL
--children 
    SELECT NextGeneration.category_id, NextGeneration.category_name, NextGeneration.category_code, Parent.child_category_id,
    CAST(CASE WHEN Parent.Parents = ''
        THEN(CAST(NextGeneration.category_parent AS VARCHAR(MAX)))
        ELSE(Parent.Parents + '.' + CAST(NextGeneration.category_parent AS VARCHAR(MAX)))
    END AS VARCHAR(MAX))
        FROM YourTable AS NextGeneration
        INNER JOIN Tree AS Parent ON NextGeneration.category_id = Parent.child_category_id    
)
SELECT *
    FROM Tree
--not needed here because you wont do that many recursions
--OPTION(MAXRECURSION 32767)
```