# JOIN table onto itself with parent id until no more rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table describing changes that has been made to an `end_customers` table. When someone changes and `end_customer` we create a new row in the `end_customers` table and add a row to `end_customer_history` table where `end_customer_parent_id` is the ID of the old `end_customer`, and `end_customer_child_id` is the ID of the new `end_customer`.

End Customer Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `end_customers` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `reference_person` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_number` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `social_security_number` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment` longtext,
  `token` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=101107 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

End Customer History Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `end_customer_history` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `end_customer_parent_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `end_customer_child_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_end_customer_parent` (`end_customer_parent_id`),
  KEY `FK_end_customer_child` (`end_customer_child_id`),
  KEY `FK_user` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `end_customer_history_old_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`end_customer_parent_id`) REFERENCES `end_customers` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `end_customer_history_old_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`end_customer_child_id`) REFERENCES `end_customers` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `end_customer_history_old_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=67 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

We are now refactoring the schema so that changes made to `end_customers` table directly edits the row instead of creating a new row, and puts a copy of the old data in a `end_customer_history_new` table that has the same schema as `end_customers`.

I need to migrate all old data to this new table.
So for each `end_customer` I have, I need to check if it has an entry in `end_customer_history` as a `end_customer_child_id` (it has been modified), and then check if that entrys parent is also present in `end_customer_history` as a child, and then check if that entrys parent is also present in `end_customer_history` as a child, and so forth until there are no more rows.

How do I do this in one migration SQL script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the solution I came up with, it doesn't use any stored functions to loop over rows, because I could never get it to work. It takes the latest version of an end customer, and then joins similar rows using a `token` that we know is always the same and unique.

```
-- Move data from old end customer history to the new schema
-- May remove some redundant history, this will be ok
-- If an end customer has been changed more than once, all changes will have the same date (latest change) and the same user responsible for change
-- This is also ok

-- Insert the latest version of changed end_customers into new history table
INSERT INTO end_customer_history (name, reference_person, phone_number, email, social_security_number, comment, end_customer_id, user_id, date)
SELECT
ec.name, ec.reference_person, ec.phone_number, ec.email, ec.social_security_number, ec.comment, ech.end_customer_child_id, ech.user_id, ech.date
FROM end_customer_history_old AS ech
JOIN end_customers AS ec ON ec.id = ech.end_customer_parent_id
WHERE ech.end_customer_child_id IN (SELECT end_customer_id FROM orders);

-- Remove all the old data
DROP TABLE end_customer_history_old;

-- Insert all versions of an end_customer based on the latest history, joined on token (always the same)
INSERT INTO end_customer_history (name, reference_person, phone_number, email, social_security_number, comment, end_customer_id, user_id, date)
SELECT
parent.name, parent.reference_person, parent.phone_number, parent.email, parent.social_security_number, parent.comment, ech.end_customer_id, ech.user_id, ech.date
FROM end_customer_history AS ech
JOIN end_customers AS ec ON ec.id = ech.end_customer_id
JOIN end_customers AS parent ON parent.token = ec.token AND parent.id <> ec.id;

-- This unfortunately creates duplicates of some rows, so it looks like changes have been made multiple times (with no new data)
-- Create a temporary table that copies over unique rows from end_customer_history
CREATE TABLE temp AS
SELECT * FROM end_customer_history
GROUP BY
name, reference_person, phone_number, email, social_security_number, comment, end_customer_id, user_id, date;

-- Clear the end_customer_history table all together
TRUNCATE TABLE end_customer_history;

-- Copy over filtered unique history rows
INSERT INTO end_customer_history (name, reference_person, phone_number, email, social_security_number, comment, end_customer_id, user_id, date)
SELECT
name, reference_person, phone_number, email, social_security_number, comment, end_customer_id, user_id, date
FROM temp;

-- Remove temporary table
DROP TABLE temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Oracle, MySQL does not provide the functionality to recursively query parent-child hierarchy. You can write a self join query (or inner queries) if you know the level beforehand. If not, you have to perform a single query and handle resursiveness in the application or stored procedure.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808784/mysql-parent-children-one-query-selection) is an example of querying a parent child hierarchy if you know the level already, and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm) is an example of how to do it in Oracle (for your reference).

Comment: I don't know the level in beforehand, but I could perhaps write a query that would handle a really deep level, that is reasonable enough to never hit. Or I could create a temporary stored procedure that handles recursivness and then deletes itself?

Comment: Stored procedure sounds good, and you don't need to delete it after it executes as you can do the `looping` into it. You just need to call the query in loop.